# загрузка json в web api

Tags: c#, json, webapi

как корректно в webapi прочитать json файл если загрузка производится с помощью

```html
<input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadFile" /><br />
<button id="submit">Загрузить</button>
```

Comment: Это ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 1):

Вся функциональность по работе с JSON в .NET Core находится в пространстве имен `System.Text.Json`.

Для работы с файлами JSON вам нужен класс, имена свойств которого должны совпадать с именами полей в файле, либо использовать аттрибут `[JsonPropertyName("field_name")]` над свойством для адаптации имени.

Например, пусть у нас будет JSON файл описывающий человека и который содержит поля Name и Email.

```
{
    "Name": "Василий",
    "Email": "vpupkin@fail.ru"
}
```

Тогда класс будет выглядеть следующим образом.

```csharp
public class JsonPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Десереализовать его можно с помощью метода `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonPerson>(jsonString)`, который принимает в качестве параметра строку типа `string` и возвращает объект того типа, которым обобщён. Тем самым на выходе вы получаете объект со всеми теми значениями полей, которые были в JSON файле.

Comment: а если json файл не возможно преобразовать в класс. И хотелось бы узнать как конкретно в контроллер передать объект

Comment: @rowwwansl 1) не может быть так, чтобы десереализовать json было не возможно, если конечно это json 2) сереализованный json - это текстовая строка, делайте с ним все, что можно делать с текстом 3) форма отправит файл как attachement, способ его получения не отличается ни чем от способа получения содержимого любого другого файла.